# Как повторить разметку из layout в коде

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

Есть код, который предназначен для встраивания в модификации программ(уж не обессудьте, но нам надо на чем-то зарабатывать) рекламы. Сейчас чтобы его добавить мне надо зарегистрировать 5 id и 1 layout, а затем поменять их в коде, что отнимает много времени. Решить проблему и сэкономить кучу времени можно создав разметку в коде, однако это оказалось куда труднее, чем в layout-ресурсе.

Прикреплю готовый layout-файл и мои потуги в создании разметки в коде, а так же скриншоты того, что было, и того, что получилось через код. Прошу помочь мне сделать хотя бы что-то похожее.

Layout-файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/adsImage"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/adsTitle"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/adsText"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom|end"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/close"
            android:text="Закрыть"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/open"
            android:text="Подробнее"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Попытки создания разметки в коде:

```
ImageView adsImage = new ImageView(this);

    TextView adsTitleView = new TextView(this);
    adsTitleView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    TextView adsTextView = new TextView(this);
    adsTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    Button open = new Button(this);
    open.setText("Подробнее");
    open.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

    Button close = new Button(this);
    close.setEnabled(false);
    open.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

    LinearLayout mainLL = new LinearLayout(this);
    mainLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    mainLL.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    mainLL.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    mainLL.addView(adsImage);
    mainLL.addView(adsTitleView);
    mainLL.addView(adsTextView);

    LinearLayout buttonLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    buttonLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    buttonLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    buttonLayout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    buttonLayout.addView(open);
    buttonLayout.addView(close);

    FrameLayout mainFL = new FrameLayout(this);
    mainFL.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    mainFL.addView(mainLL);
    mainFL.addView(buttonLayout);

    setContentView(mainFL);
```

Скрины(Layout/код):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WB3uX.png / https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rg0xg.png

Comment: Причем если убрать кнопки и сделать только один LinearLayout с 2 текствью и одной картинкой, то все работает, но кнопки нужны и как на скрине, у меня получается только криво под текствью добавить.

Comment: У большинства атрибутов разметки есть метод-аналог - в документации классов-виджетов они указаны. Думаю проблема в `setLayoutParams` - здесь нужно задать параметры размещения в родительском контейнере, у каждого  контейнера свой класс `LatoutParams` и детям нужно задавать именно его. В `LatoutParams` нужно перенести значения атрибутов с префиксом `android:layout_` Немножко в примерах и картинках: https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/49-16-layoutparams.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все таки сделал сам, на это ушла куча времени гугления. Вот конечный результат, повторил полностью

```
ImageView adsImage = new ImageView(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams adsImageParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adsImageParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    adsImage.setLayoutParams(adsImageParams);

    TextView adsTitleView = new TextView(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams adsTitleViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adsTitleViewParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    adsTitleView.setLayoutParams(adsTitleViewParams);
    adsTitleView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    TextView adsTextView = new TextView(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams adsTextViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adsTextViewParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    adsTextView.setLayoutParams(adsTextViewParams);
    adsTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    Button open = new Button(this, null, android.R.attr.buttonBarButtonStyle);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams openParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    openParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    open.setLayoutParams(openParams);
    open.setText("Подробнее");

    Button close = new Button(this, null, android.R.attr.buttonBarButtonStyle);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams closeParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    closeParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    close.setLayoutParams(closeParams);
    close.setEnabled(false);

    LinearLayout contentLL = new LinearLayout(this);
    contentLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams contentLLParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    contentLLParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    contentLL.setLayoutParams(contentLLParams);
    contentLL.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    contentLL.addView(adsImage);
    contentLL.addView(adsTitleView);
    contentLL.addView(adsTextView);

    LinearLayout buttonLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams buttonLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    buttonLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT|Gravity.BOTTOM;
    buttonLayout.setLayoutParams(buttonLayoutParams);
    buttonLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    buttonLayout.addView(open);
    buttonLayout.addView(close);

    FrameLayout mainL = new FrameLayout(this);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams mainLParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    mainL.setLayoutParams(mainLParams);
    mainL.addView(contentLL);
    mainL.addView(buttonLayout);

    setContentView(mainL);
```